# Qt Item roles realization

Tags: c++, qt

How is Qt Item roles mechanism realized? Just some kind of map stored inside classes that support roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item roles are used to retrieve different data for a given model index, e.g. the text, icon, tooltip etc. in a list model. How they are implemented depends on the model.

QStandardItemModel indeed uses a QMap (role to value) internally.

For custom models, usually one uses if or switch statements to return different data for different roles:

```
QVector<SomeObject> m_data;

QVariant SomeListModel::data( const QModelIndex& index, int role ) const {
    const SomeObject& so = m_data[index.row()];
    switch ( role ) {
    case Qt::DisplayRole:
        return so.name();
    case Qt::DecorationRole:
        return so.icon();
    case Qt::ToolTipRole:
        return so.details();
    case SomeObjectRole: // Custom role, SomeObjectRole=Qt::UserRole
        return QVariant::fromValue<SomeObject>( so );
    default:
        break;
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

Fast index() and data() methods are important to get efficient models, so avoid map lookups and everything else that's not O(1) in relation to the number of items (size of m_data here).